# js onclick for newly created element

Tags: javascript, onclick, onclicklistener

Hi I am trying to create a simple colorpicker for my project. It should dispalay DIV vith colored SPANS and each span should onclick call my function -pickColor()- with its onwn value.

The problem is that, after clicking on any Span my function is simply called with last walue from my array instead of the coresponding one. Any idea how to correct it?

here is my code

```
var colors = [ "303030", "777777", "da0025", "f01800", "ff4300", "fd6c05", "feab07", "ffc91e", "93c900", "54c300", "00ab62", "00c3c4", "009bf0", "006afe", "3f00dd", "9025ff", "ff3ec2", "fe0b6b"];
```

//color picker
var picker;

```
function createPicker(){
//create picker wrapper
picker = document.createElement('div');
picker.id = "colorPicker";
picker.style.display = "none"; // initialy invisible !
picker.style.margin = "0";
picker.style.padding = "0.5em";
picker.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(30,30,30)";
//create picker color options
var newColor;
for (var i = colors.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    newColor = document.createElement('span');
    newColor.id = colors[i];
    //set style for color option
    newColor.style.display = "inline-block";
    newColor.style.width = "50px";
    newColor.style.height = "50px";
    newColor.style.margin = "0";
    newColor.style.padding = "0";
    newColor.style.backgroundColor = "#"+colors[i];
    //add onclick function

    newColor.addEventListener("click", function f(){pickColor( colors[i] )}, true);

    //append option
    picker.appendChild(newColor);
};
//append colorPicker to file
document.getElementById('here').appendChild(picker); // value must be set to the parent elements id !
}

function displayPicker(){
picker.style.display = "inline-block";
}

function pickColor(id){
//set value
console.log(id);
var input = document.getElementById('color'); // must be the 'input' elements id that we want to set !
//console.log(input);
input.value = id;
// hide picker
picker.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at Teemu's recommend link (thanks), I realized that it gets quite tricky if you use `function` in `addEventListener` method call within a loop.

So how about doing this way, without any parameters:

```
newColor.addEventListener("click", pickColor, true);
```

In the pickColor function you can access the `id` in the following way:

```
function pickColor(){

   var id = this.id;
   //more code below

}
```

Comment: but what is 'this' in this instance?

Comment: @joasisk Very good question :-) Here is a quote for an answer: 'In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of. ... An onclick property, though, is owned by the HTML element it belongs to.' Source: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: thanks it is werry helpful since Im a newbee and am learning by doing

Comment: this will definately help a lot in future

Comment: @joasisk I'm glad that I was able to provide some assistance :-) I remember when I was doing similar type of event handling for the very first time, I found it really tricky, and spend hours trying to figure out whats going on with dynamically created elements and their event handling. Anyway, you are doing great and progressing really well with JavaScript!

Answer (score 2):

Closure is nice though sometimes a bit confusing. Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLnvanxs/3/) with the problem (I hope) solved and here's the js code that made it possible:

```
newColor.addEventListener("click", (function (param) {
            return function() {
                pickColor(colors[param]);
            };
        })(i), true);
```

The problem was that, due to closure, i value was -1. Yo have to pass the actual value of i to the function and, thanks to closure, use it in the function that you'll end up returning and using for the event.

**UPDATE**

Better approach: define function somewhere in your code:

```
function clickEvHandlerClosure(param) {
    return function () {
        pickColor(colors[param]);
    };
}
```

and then:

```
newColor.addEventListener("click", clickEvHandlerClosure(i), true);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLnvanxs/4/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: This won't pass JSLint ("Don't create functions in loops"), it does the job though.

Comment: @Teemu he,he well... that wasn't requested in the first place. Secondly, I sincerely doubt that most of the js scripts seen in stackoverflow would pass JSLint.

Comment: thank you werry much it helped a lot

Comment: Probably they wouldn't. But it's bad practice to create functions within loops, it increases memory and CPU time consumption. The IIFE here could be replaced with a pre-declared function very easily.

Comment: @Teemu thanks for your feedback. I've updated the answer. Do you like it best?

Comment: Definitely better, +1 ; ).